# Three.js pbr Solution

Tags: three.js, pbr

I know toolbag and playcanvas best support PBR (physical based rendering). What pbr solution in three.js?

Please give some link or example.

[toolbag pbr](https://www.marmoset.co/wp-content/uploads/tb2/ssr_full.jpg)

[playcanvas pbr](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B4ggGLoCAAM-nnY.jpg:large)

Answer (score 3):

Below are some Three.js examples using PBR:

- [WebGLpbr](https://github.com/tiansijie/WebGLpbr)
- http://amine.dai.free.fr/three.js/pbr.html

Comment: Nice finds. Though with the demo of the first one I am seeing some weird pulsing in the specular highlights. Setting the roughness up allows you to see it more clear. Do you see it too or is it just my machine? http://sijietian.com/WebGL/pbr/

Comment: WebGLpbr:I also seeing some weird pulsing in the specular highlights

Comment: here is one http://dusanbosnjak.com/test/webGL/new/pbr/poredjenjeNormalaBias.html

Comment: Only the one in comment is using IBL (Image Based Lighting) though, which is the most common use of PBR.

Answer (score 2):

The Khronos [gltf](/questions/tagged/gltf) format now has a [proposed PBR extension](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/pull/643) in the works.  The long-term goal is to have a standard 3D model format with PBR capability that is supported by Three.js and many other rendering engines.

As of this writing (Sept 2016) this is still in the early stages and there are no examples to share yet.  Interested parties may [track the list of PBR issues](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/labels/PBR) to follow along with the progress.

Answer (score 1):

Check out `THREE.MeshStandardMaterial`.  You get `metalness` and `roughness` properties along with the usual `normal` and `ao`

http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/MeshStandardMaterial